# PropertyGroupDescription не группировать со значением null

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Как я могу изменить группировку в xaml при использовании **PropertyGroupDescription**
чтобы не группировались элементы коллекции у которых **PropertyName = null**?

```
<CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
    <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="BlankType" />
</CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
```

Весь остальной код создает окно с выпадающими списками сгруппированными по **BlankType**, когда значение свойства **null**, отображается выпадающий список с пустым названием. Я не могу добиться поведения при котором элементы списка со значением **null** не будут группироваться.

Comment: У `ICollectionView` есть свойство `Filter`, туда можно засунуть фильтрующий делегат и просто выкинуть это из коллекции.

Comment: мне не нужно исключать из коллекции элементы, просто не группировать их